# Is there a good pattern to follow for multi version OSS development?

Tags: git, version-control

My OSS contributions normally only has a master branch that moves forward through time with semantic versioning.

I have a changelog that goes all the way back to the initial release.

I use git tags for the releases.

Packagist is happy. Users are happy.

Today a bug has been found that relates to an older version that needs to be fixed.

What I think I need to do is branch off the last release of that version (v2.9.6 tag => the new v2 branch), fix in the v2 branch and release from that branch.

But I also want/need to update the changelog and anything else that's required.

What I'd like to know is are there any good pattern to follow in terms of branch naming conventions, changelog (1 per version or just 1), etc.

Should I also create branches for all the major versions?

I know this is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds quite reasonable. You probably want to follow [semantic versioning](http://semver.org) if you don’t already, so that a bug fix for 2.9.6 would be 2.9.7 (or 2.9.6.1, if you follow the convention that Haskell packages use).

Develop the bugfix on a feature branch, of course. That way you can also merge it into the master branch if it’s needed.

I’m not sure what you’re asking about the changelog. In general there should be a changelog entry for every feature that gets merged into the release.